# MySql, search columns that have two keywords in BOOLEAN MODE

Tags: php, mysql

I made a search system for my website.

Let's say there are 5 datas in the database.

1. Apple macbook air review
2. Apple iMac review
3. Apple iPhone review
4. iPhone 4 unboxing review
5. iPhone jailbreak review

A user types 'iphone review' on the search input.

I would like to show the result like this

1. Apple **iPhone review**
2. **iPhone** 4 unboxing **review**
3. **iPhone** jailbreak **review**

I could sucessfully break the search words and used boolean mode.

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKMARK WHERE MATCH title AGAINST ('iphone* review*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But it won't show the result like above.

It searchs for data that have iphone or review word.

Can you help me to figure this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKMARK WHERE MATCH title AGAINST ('"iphone review"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This one worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `+` sign in front of the word, to ensure it is present in each hit.

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKMARK WHERE MATCH title AGAINST ('+iphone +review' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

For more information see the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html)